# How can I recognize a specific Postgres CONSTRAINT

Tags: java, postgresql, exception, jdbc, jdbi

We used to have a constraint in the (Java) *domain logic* that prevented an entity `(foo,task_id)` of being inserted into table `entity_a` if a that `task_id` was already present. We then threw a specific exception that could be listened for.

Now we moved that logic into the database where it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE report ADD CONSTRAINT task_id_unique UNIQUE (task_id);
```

Now I still want to throw the same exception as before, but I need to recognize the specific exception case thrown by the database layer to do this. Is there a somewhat stable way I can recognize the named constraint? It should preferably not depend on the language set on the server, as it could be different and I also know error messages are different from one Postgres version to another.

We are specifically using [Jdbi](https://jdbi.org/) which is very close to the underlying JDBC level, so getting any details should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the `java.sql.SQLException` to an [`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html). Then you can call the method [`getServerErrorMessage()`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html#getServerErrorMessage--) to get an [`org.postgresql.util.ServerErrorMessage`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/ServerErrorMessage.html). Then call the method [`getConstraint()`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/ServerErrorMessage.html#getConstraint--) to get the name of the constraint. Check the SQLSTATE to make sure it was really a constraint violation.